# HTML5 validation check input bigger than 0

Tags: html, validation

I have an input field which be should **bigger than 0**, I'm using `min="0.00000001"` to validate input number is > 0.

```
<input type="number" step="0.00000001" min="0.00000001" name="price" value="[%price%]" />
```

**Since I don't want to specify the `step` and `min`, I just want to validate if the input number is bigger than 0.**

Is there any better way to compare input? For example something like `input > 0` or `min > 0`

I search for a solution but could not find one without using `step`+`min`.

**Using only html5, can we do this? Thanks for any help**

```html
<form method="post">
  <b>Number Input:</b>
  <input type="number" step="0.00000001" min="0.00000001" name="number" value="" />
  <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

Comment: did you try to use `pattern`, something like `^[1-9]*$`?

Comment: @mxr7350 I will give a try, thank you first.

Comment: @mxr7350 it does not prevent me to submit 0

Comment: `pattern` is disallowed and ignored for `type="number"` (besides, `^[1-9]*$`, if it worked, would restrict too much, rejecting e.g. 0.1).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Good to know, so I can only use `step` and `min` to valid a number bigger than 0? Or I can change the type to text?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no way doing this in pure HTML5 without JavaScript. As mentioned in comments, the `pattern` attribute cannot be used.

But this can be handled using trivial JavaScript code, invoked via the `oninput` attribute, and using `setCustomValidity`:

```html
<form method="post">
  <b>Number Input:</b>
  <input type="number" step="any" min="0"  name="number" value="" 
         oninput="check(this)" />
  <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
<script>
 function check(input) {
   if (input.value == 0) {
     input.setCustomValidity('The number must not be zero.');
   } else {
     // input is fine -- reset the error message
     input.setCustomValidity('');
   }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: thanks, I think I have to go with js to do this, thanks